# Why does Professor Zawadzki eat worms?

Tags: monsters-of-krakow

We see that while farming, Professor Zawadzki eats an earthworm, and he seems to have earthworms in soil around his office (to munch on?). Of course, earthworms *are* consumed occasionally in some parts of the world, but so far as I know, they are not known for being popular in Poland, and much less while still alive.

Does this have some supernatural significance? Based on the elemental themes of the series, perhaps it can connect him somehow to the gods of the earth? Or does Zawadzki just have unusual tastes?

Comment: I resisted saying "Why does Professor Zawadzki believe in the Diet of Worms?"

Comment: Nobody likes him, everybody hates him...

Comment: A better question is why you don't.